# Economy/diseconomy of scale. Is economy a positive word?

Tags: word-usage

*Economy of scale* means that as a company's production increases, the marginal cost of production goes down and therefore profit per product goes **up**.

When profit per product goes **down** with scale, this is called *diseconomy of scale*.

Why is diseconomy used here, and why is that word almost never used anywhere else? You say Greece is (or has) a *bad economy*, not is a diseconomy.
Why is economy a positive word here, when it is a neutral in other contexts?

Comment: There is a misconception that related word-forms (eg verbs and nouns) map across to each other either precisely or very closely in their most common meanings. 'Idiom' (primary meaning: a set expression with unusual meaning of words and/or unusual grammar) and 'idiomatic' (primary meaning: 'commonly used') show that the first is not true. 'Telescope' (n) and 'telescope' (v) show that the second isn't either. // Why? The best answer that can usually be given is the C- 'That's the way people have generally decided to use these words'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ***[diseconomy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diseconomy)*** here refers to the concept of "lower efficency" not to the Ecomony of a country, that is "*the system or range of economic activity in a country, region, or community"*.

> - (Economics) economics disadvantage, such as lower efficiency or higher average costs, resulting from the scale on which an enterprise produces goods or services

It is the opposite of [economy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/economy) meaning:

> - Careful, thrifty management of resources, such as money, materials, or labor.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: But when used adjectivally, or adverbially, it  becomes *uneconomic*, *uneconomical* and *uneconomically* - never *diseconomical*.

Comment: @WS2      Uneconomical: *not economical; wasteful*  - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uneconomical.. That is another term, from economical with a different connotation. Diseconomy is an economics concept.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Josh61's great answer on *diseconomy*, the noun *economy* has multiple meanings. It sometimes has a connotation of something being saved as the verb to [*eononomize*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/economize) indicates:

> Spend less; reduce one’s expenses: '*I have to economize where I can*.'
>   '*people on low incomes may try to economize on fuel*.'

In "economy of scale", *economy* means a proportionate **saving in costs** gained by an increased **scale** which means an increased level of production.

If you could increase your profit by decreasing your costs, it is a good thing. That's why it could be a positive word in *economy of scale*.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: I accept that your and Josh61's answers are correct, but this usage of the word bugs me since it doesn't line up with the every day usage of the word.
Saying _Positive_, or _Negative_ economy of scale seems closer to "normal" definition, and _Economy of scale_ should just be the concept of how economies are affected by scale, not positive or negative.